# no operator matches these operands ofstream >> string

Tags: c++

Trying to count the number of similar items in the text file after writing the text but i am getting an `No operator << matches these operands operand type are std::ofstream >> std::string` . Code works but when adding the while loop is where i get the error  `textfile >> item`. Does it have anything to do with ofstream of the textfile?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string accord[6];

    ofstream textfile;
    textfile.open("C:\\temp\\1.txt");

    cout << "Enter a 6 cylinder car : " << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        getline(cin, accord[x]);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {

        textfile << accord[x] << endl;
    }
    int count = 0;
    string item;
    while (!textfile.eof()) {
        textfile >> item;
        if (item == "6") {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << count << "found!" << endl;



    textfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ofstream` means output file stream. You can't read and write at the same time. Use `ifstream` for read

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because, as the error suggests, the class [`std::ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) does not have that operator.

> Ofstream: Output stream class to operate on files.

As you can imagine by yourself, an output stream is an object designed to write on (output). So you're not allowed input operation.

[`std::fstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) is a both output and input stream for file. It supports `operator<<` `operator>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `textfile` is declared as having type `std::ofstream`

```
ofstream textfile;
```

There is no `operator >>` defined for objects of this type,

You should at first close the file and use an object of type `std::ifstream` with this file to read data from it.